# Comparing Two DB's in a cron job to send a mail notification

Tags: mysql, cron, multiple-databases

Cron job:

Import a csv file into MySQL $db1.
Establish a new connection to $db2 and create new $db1.table with data from $db2.

I am stuck wondering how to compare the results of these two databases and to email a notification during the cron job if any of the rows match from $db1.csvtable to $db1.db2table?

Am I approaching this project the correct way? There is no way to compare results by unique id so my best guess was to compare each column as the databases aren't too large.

Thanks for your help and let me know if there needs to be any clarifying. 
(using php-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to dump the data to disk as ordered flat files and then use `comm` to find the matching lines.

Something like this:

```
mysql -h db1 -e "select * into outfile '/tmp/db1.txt' from your_table order by id;"
mysql -h db2 -e "select * into outfile '/tmp/db2.txt' from your_table order by id;"
comm -1 -2 /tmp/db1.txt /tmp/db2.txt > /tmp/matching.txt
```

Comment: does this create a new txt file with the matching rows?

Comment: i'm receiving a "Unkown MySQL server host" when I execute the command. is -h supposed to be database name or hostname?

Comment: i'm sorry but i lack linux knowledge. i'm hoping you can help me execute this script successfully.

Comment: where would i put this script? currently to test, I'm using putty but keep generating errors.

Comment: I assumed when you asked about 2 databases you meant 2 separate hosts, which is why I included -h in my example. If you're actually talking about 2 schemas in the same MySQL instance then you wouldn't need -h (and you could actually do the comparison in MySQL if you want). As for where to put it, you can put the commands in a shell script and invoke the script from cron.

Comment: if i get access denied where do i change permissions to grant access?